# Ошибка "SQL logic error or missing database near "(": syntax error"

Tags: c#, sqlite

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;


namespace WorkSQLite
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Data_Connection db_object = new Data_Connection();
        SQLiteConnection SQLiteConnect = new SQLiteConnection();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnect.ConnectionString = db_object.datalocation();
        SQLiteConnect.Open();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteCommand SQLCommand = new SQLiteCommand();
        SQLCommand = SQLiteConnect.CreateCommand();
        SQLCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + textBox1.Text + "( Username TEXT, Password TEXT);";
        SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SQLCommand.Dispose();

        MessageBox.Show("Table Created");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        cmd = SQLiteConnect.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into " + textBox1.Text + " (Username,Password)  values (@username,@password)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();

        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from " + textBox1.Text, SQLiteConnect);
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Data Exist in Table");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Выбрасывает ошибку во время вставки данных в базу данных SQLite. Ошибка указывает на это:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Вроде все верно... В чем ошибка?

[image: Прикрепляю скриншот окна ошибки]

Comment: Вы в дебаге смотрели какой конечный вид принимает ваш запрос после подставления textBox1.Text?

Comment: хотя бы исключение пришлите, а то тут хрустальный шар не поможет даже